# Plotting multiple variable function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-arguments

I'm needing help with the following question:

Consider the following R function, named `negloglike` that has two input arguments: `lam` and `x`, in that order.
Use this function to produce a plot of the log-likelihood function over a range of values λ ∈ (0, 2).

```
negloglike <- function(lam, x) {
  l = -sum(log(dexp(x, lam)))
  return(l)
}
```

Can anyone please help? Is it possible to do something like this with ggplot? I've been trying to do it with a set value of `lam` (like `0.2` here for example) using `stat_function`:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = negloglike, args = list(lam = 0.2)) +
  xlim(0,10)
```

but the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geLLV.png) always returns a horizontal line at some y-value instead of returning a curve.

Should I be possibly using a different geom? Or even a different package altogether?

Much appreciated!

Comment: You should edit **the question** and post the code you have used. To know what you are doing is a first step to know what is wrong with it. Tip: I would start by swapping the order of the arguments, `x` first.

Comment: Also, it's `-log(sum(.))`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've added in my code to the question. The `negloglike` function works fine when I'm using it to calculate values but the graph that is produced by `stat_function` doesn't work the same (with the way that I've done it anyway). Changing it to `-log(sum(.))` doesn't seem to make any difference, nor does swapping the order of `x` and `lam`

Comment: Note that the function sums over all values of `dexp`, so it will return one value only.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that usually the case when plotting a function? To plot one value for every x-value? Or am I misunderstanding the way the mechanics work? e.g. `negloglike(x = 1, lam = 0.2) = 1.809438`, `negloglike(x = 2, lam = 0.2) = 2.009438` etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to `Vectorize` the function over the argument of interest.
Thanks for the tip go to the most voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671515/how-to-graph-the-log-likelihood-function). It uses base graphics only, so here is a `ggplot2` equivalent.
First I will define the negative log-likelihood using function `dexp`

```
library(ggplot2)

negloglike <- function(lam, x) {negloglike <- function(lam, x) {
    l = -sum(dexp(x, lam, log = TRUE))
    return(l)
}
nllv <- Vectorize(negloglike, "lam")
```

But it's better to use the analytic form, which is easy to establish by hand.

```
negloglike2 <- function(lam, x) {
    l = lam*sum(x) - length(x)*log(lam)
    return(l)
}

nllv2 <- Vectorize(negloglike2, "lam")

ggplot(data = data.frame(lam = seq(0, 2, by = 0.2)), mapping = aes(x = lam)) +
  stat_function(fun = nllv2, args = list(x = 0:10))
```

[image]

Both `nllv` and `nllv2` give the same graph.

Comment: Awesome Rui, thanks so much! This helped heaps. I thought there had to be some vectorising in some shape or form after reading a couple of posts but I wasn't really sure about how to apply it here.

Comment: @ethy_32 Sorry but I made a mistake with the log-likelihood. See the new code and graph.